# Why is a error message when I try to debug?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm trying to learn c++, so I decided to try spliting my code but I have a problem, Visual studio show an error message. Can anybody help me please? (This is a code where i'm learning so it might seem to be useless) Here's the main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "math.hpp"

using namespace std;


string demanderProg()
{
    cout << "Entrez le nom du code a executer :" << endl;
    string prog;
    cin >> prog;
    return prog;
}

void dessineRectangle(int l, int h)
{
    cout << "Quel symbole voulez vous utilisez pour votre rectangle?" << endl;
    char symbole;
    cin >> symbole;
    cout << endl;
    for (int ligne(0); ligne < h; ligne++)
    {
        for (int colonne(0); colonne < l; colonne++)
        {
            cout << symbole;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    string prog1 = "boucle", prog2 = "carre", prog3 = "dessineRec", prog4 = "echange", progRecu = demanderProg();
    if (progRecu == prog1)
    {
        double n1(0), n2, n3, n4(0);
        cout << "De combien voulez vous augmentez a chaque tour de boucle?" << endl;
        cin >> n2;
        cout << "Combien tour de boucle voulez vous faire?" << endl;
        cin >> n3;
        for (n1 == 0; n1 < n3; n1++)
        {
            n4 += n2;
            cout << endl << n4 << endl;
        }
    }
    else if (progRecu == prog2)
    {
        double nombre;
        cout << "Donnez moi un nombre et je vous donne son carre :" << endl;
        cin >> nombre;
        double nombreCarre = racineCarre(nombre);
        cout << "Le carre de " << nombre << " est " << nombreCarre;
    }
    else if (progRecu == prog3)
    {
        int largeur, hauteur;
        cout << "Largeur du rectangle : ";
        cin >> largeur;
        cout << "Hauteur du rectangle : ";
        cin >> hauteur;
        if (largeur <= 0 || hauteur <= 0)
        {
            cout << "Valeur nul ou negatif!" << endl;
        }

        dessineRectangle(largeur, hauteur);
    }
    else if (progRecu == prog4)
    {
        cout << "Donnez moi deux valeur et je vais les echanger (comme cela : n1 n2)" << endl;
        double n1, n2;
        cin >> n1 >> n2;
        echange(n1, n2);
        cout << "Maintenant n1 vaut " << n1 << " et " << "n2 vaut " << n2 << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Ce programme n'existe pas!" << endl;
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Here's is the math.cpp :

```
#include "math.hpp"

double racineCarre(double x)
{
    return x * x;
}

void echange(double& n1, double& n2)
{
    double n3(n1);
    n1 = n2;
    n2 = n3;
}
```

And this is my math.hpp:

```
#ifndef MATH_H_INCLUDED
#define MATH_H_INCLUDED

double racineCarre(double x);
void echange(double& n1, double& n2);

#endif
```

[Here's a pic of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kFdS.png)

Comment: Most likely, you haven't actually added `math.cpp` to the project.

Comment: How can i add it?

Comment: In Visual Studio, choose `Project > Add existing item` from the menu.